# Why JS async function shows neither print nor error?

Tags: javascript

My code

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Tutorial = require('./models/Tutorial');

async function createTutorial() {
  try {
    console.log('guy Incognito');
    const doc = await Tutorial.create({ title: 'bill ', body: 'Bill Russel was great player!' });
    console.log(`randomTextabcde\n${doc}`);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

createTutorial();
```

In models/Tutorials

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const TutorialSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  body: String,
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Tutorial', TutorialSchema);
```

When I run my code from terminal,

```
node index.js
```

shows

```
guy Incognito
```

It seems that promise is not resolved..
Why?

Comment: Maybe when you log the correct error: `console.log(err)`

Comment: What is `doc instanceof Tutorial;` supposed to do?

Comment: @GuyIncognito Valeri Karpov tutorial has that line. Checks instance type,I guess.

Comment: @Andreas The same,you can try.

Comment: It doesn't do anything by its own.

Comment: also for the try block, in case doc is an empty return, replace with `console.log(\`randomTextabcde\n${doc}\`)`

Comment: @GuyIncognito I deleted the line.

Comment: Aside from the ReferenceError that @Andreas pointed out, and the fact that you have `doc instanceof Tutorial;` standing on its own so you never see the result of that expression, that code is fine and `createTutorial` will definitely call `console.log` or `console.error` ***if*** the promise from `Tutorial.create` is ever settled. If that promise never settles, `createTutorial` won't show anything because it'll just sit at the `await` forever. So if you're not seeing anything, that would suggest that the promise from `Tutorial.create` is never settled.

Comment: @TheBombSquad Again ,the same.Something to do with function invocation.

Comment: Put some console.log as the first line of the function to make sure that it's being called. Also if this is all the code you have, you're not connecting to the database.

Comment: yea either something's up with ur database, or something's up with moose if u still see nothing after that step

Comment: Your best bet here, as is usually the case, is to use the debugger built into your IDE and/or browser to put a breakpoint on the first statement (at least) of the function and then step through it statement by statement, watching what happens.

Comment: start console.logging line by line and see bit by bit what goes down

Comment: @TheBombSquad - Or, rather than wandering around in the dark with a `console.log` torch, *turn on the lights* with the debugger. :-)

Comment: he says there is no error logging, else we wouldn't be here

Comment: woww that is strange..

Comment: apparently doc is never declared? the try function is called, the catch isn't but declaring const doc just exits???

Comment: ok comment out the line that says const doc for a bit and just have another line right below it saying console.log(await EVERYTHING-U-HAD-FOR-DOC)

Comment: Do you have a working connection to your database? Mongoose won't throw an error if you don't have one and the request will just be buffered.

Comment: @P.E.Joëssel - Oh, wow -- no timeout?!

Comment: @P.E.Joëssel Thanks,that was the catch! Works perfect.

Comment: @P.E.Joëssel Why err was not throwned?

Comment: @MikiBelavista please see answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't have a correct connection to your database. If I take your exact code, everything is working fine with a correct connection and behave as described in your question with no connection.

To create a connection call `mongoose.connect('mongodb://<db_uri>', {useNewUrlParser: true});`  somewhere in your app.

To understand why your code didn't throw any error and you had no log, you can read more about how mongoose handle connection [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#buffering)

Answer (score 0):

A working connection to MongoDB must be established.

```
mongoose
  .connect('mongodb://localhost/stackoverflow_db', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => console.log('Successfully connect to MongoDB.'))
  .catch((err) => console.error('Connection error', err));
```